# Saving User ID and value in a JSON File

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Im trying to add the user's id as a key and a value. Right now, the user's id is not displayed in the JSON file but only the value.

Im using a evg file from https://github.com/Cannicide/scav-bot/blob/master/evg.js

This is the command which adds a new user to the JSON file

```
var userValues = new Discord.Collection();
....
 const userid = message.author.id;
    
    
    if (!userValues.has(userid)){
        userValues.set(userid, 10);
        userfile.setLS(userValues);
    };
```

This is in another file which changes the user's value

```
var currentBalance = userValues.get(userid);
        userValues.get(userid) = currentBalance + coins;
        userfile1.setLS(userValues);
```

I'm not sure what is wrong, but command prompt says the left hand assignment is invalid

`userValues.get(userid) = currentBalance + coins;`

Answer (score 1):

`userValues.get(userid)` is a return value from the get method, You cannot change it's value, this is true for any function. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Invalid_assignment_left-hand_side)

`userValues.get(userid) = currentBalance + coins;`

Instead you will need to use the set helper function:

`userValues.set(currentBalance + coins);`